# Is it possible to connect a WiFi route to some server and forward every connection to that server?

Tags: networking, network-manager, security, vpn, iptables

I'm facing some package loss issues I'm having in my home-network. I'm looking at some log entries and some game reports I've detected, a somewhat strange IP route added, and a snort made me some notifications about SCANS constantly from my router, even that I've not established any connection.
My router has enabled UPnP and I don't have the password to disable it.

Can I make some script to encrypt the send of packages?
Is a VPN a safe way to protect from sniffers?

Comment: No. A VPN won't probably help you. Encrypting your packets won't also help you. With the given information, it's hard to tell you what may be the root problem of your issue.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting